# Add an Update SQL Query on a Pentaho Kettle Transformation

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have a scenario where I would like to run an update script after a table input and table output job, can anyone assist? I have tried these four but I can't seem to figure out how to make them work.

[My Current Transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itS7V.png)

Here's the scenario...

Table Input: MySQL Database Table1 (*Select * from Table1*)

Table Output: Oracle Database (*Create Table 1*)

(*this runs well to completion but then I have to execute the update script manually. I am looking for a way to automate this*)

The update query I would like to run:

*update odb.table1 set colum1='New Value1' where column1='Old Value1'

update odb.table1 set colum1='New Value2' where column1='Old Value2'*

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Execute SQL Script tool. I just added the two update queries separated by a semicolon ;.

I created two transformations. One for the table input and table output and another for the Execute SQL Script Tool.
I then created a Kettle Job and placed my query after the table output transformation.